# Getting TestNG to fail a test if file does not exist in location

Tags: selenium, testng

I have a test case which downloads a report from my website to my downloads folder. I want TestNG to fail the test if the file does not download (i.e. it doesn't exist in my downloads folder) but I can't get it to fail. I'm new to Java AND TestNG and I'm going on maternity leave in a week. Please help a girl out. Here's what I've got so far.
Thank you!

```
package trailerreports;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;

public class TrailerSummaryReport {
@Test
public void Run() throws InterruptedException {

      System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Selenium\\chromedriver.exe");

        WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get("https://uat.mixtelematics.com/#/login");
        driver.findElement(By.name("userName")).sendKeys("xx@mixtelematics.com");       
        driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys("xxxxx");      
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@ng-class='buttonClass()']")).click();     
        driver.get("https://uat.mixtelematics.com/#/insight/reports/setup?orgId=3141559618424543932&path=%2FFM%2FTrailer%20Reports%2FTrailer%20Summary%20Report");                      driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".first-item > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(2)")).click();     
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//BUTTON[@class='btn-wide btn-small btn-success btn ng-scope ng-binding'][text()='Next']")).click();       
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a.btn-success:nth-child(1)")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("th.selection")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//BUTTON[@class='btn ng-scope ng-binding btn-wide btn-success'][text()='Select']")).click();       
        Select dropdown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("select.span3")));
        dropdown.selectByVisibleText("Year to Date");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//BUTTON[@class='btn-wide btn-small btn-success btn ng-scope ng-binding'][text()='Next']")).click();
        Select dropdown5 = new Select(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.form-inline:nth-child(2) > select:nth-child(2)")));
        dropdown5.selectByVisibleText("Download");
        Select dropdown6 = new Select(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span.report-parameter:nth-child(4) > span:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(2) > select:nth-child(2)")));
        dropdown6.selectByVisibleText("PDF");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//BUTTON[@class='btn-wide btn-small btn-success btn ng-scope ng-binding'][text()='Run']")).click();      

  } 

  @Test
  public void Download() throws InterruptedException {

        File f = new File("C://Users//lisar//Downloads/Trailer Summary Report.pdf");
          if(f.exists()){
              System.out.println("File exists");

     }        
  }
}
```

[image: File doesn't exist]
[image: TestNG still passes Download test]

Comment: you missed a slash here:
File f = new File("C://Users//lisar//Downloads/Trailer Summary Report.pdf");

Comment: Well spotted, thanks M3trix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File object will return whether its a valid path or not. f.exists() will return true or false. As the file is not present at the path it is returning false and since you have not handled the else part it is not getting displayed on the console.

If you want to throw exception while reading the file then you should use FileInputStream

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("path of file..");
```

This will return an exception if the file is not present at the path.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you :)